# Stored Procedure IF Exist Update Else Insert, if match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a lot of help form different articles, for which i thank you a lot.
But, right now i have a case were i need your support namely related with an SQL procedure which not only is checking if data exists (for update or insert it, but i have to match it with other 2 tables to check if data is matching then insert the same row with different values for some columns on a separate table).

I hope to be more explicit, so the example below I hope to help

Main row data : **db.Table1**

```
|rowID|PurchaseDate|ProducID  | ProductName |   CustomerID |    Qty |   UnitType|
|row1 |09.09.2018  |206       | Prod1       |   1          |    10  |   bl.     |
|row2 |09.09.2018  |207       | Prod2       |   2          |    15  |   bl.     |
|row3 |12.09.2018  |203       | Prod5       |   5          |    5   |   lk.     |
|row4 |15.09.2018  |207       | Prod2       |   6          |    10  |   lk.     |
|row5 |20.09.2018  |207       | Prod2       |   8          |    3   |   Pk.     |
|row6 |20.09.2018  |203       | Prod5       |   8          |    6   |   Pk.     |
|row7 |20.09.2018  |205       | Prod0       |   2          |    5   |   J.      |
```

to match with: **db.Table2**

```
|CustomerID|    CustomerName|
|1         |    Customer1   |
|2         |    Customer2   |
|3         |    Customer3   |
|4         |    Customer4   |
|5         |    Customer5   |
```

to match with: **db.Table3**

```
|ProducID|  ProductName|    SubProdNAME| |
|205     |  Prod0      |    Prod101    |
|205     |  Prod0      |    Prod202    |
|204     |  Prod01     |    Prod1001   |
|204     |  Prod01     |    Prod2002   |
```

to final table: **db.TableFIN**

```
|rowID| PurchaseDate|ProducID|ProductName|CustomerID|Qty|UnitType |Stage|
|row1 | 09.09.2018  |   206  |  Prod1    |  1       |10 |   bl.   | DONE|
|row1 | 09.09.2018  |   206  |  Prod1    |  1       |10 |   bl.   | NONE|
|row2 | 09.09.2018  |   207  |  Prod2    |  2       |15 |   bl.   | DONE|
|row2 | 09.09.2018  |   207  |  Prod2    |  2       |15 |   bl.   | NONE|
|row3 | 12.09.2018  |   203  |  Prod5    |  5       |5  |   lk.   | DONE|
|row3 | 12.09.2018  |   203  |  Prod5    |  5       |5  |   lk.   | NONE|
|row4 | 15.09.2018  |   207  |  Prod2    |  6       |10 |   lk.   | DONE|
|row4 | 15.09.2018  |   207  |  Prod2    |  6       |0  |   lk.   | NONE|
|row5 | 20.09.2018  |   207  |  Prod2    |  8       |3  |   Pk.   | DONE|
|row5 | 20.09.2018  |   207  |  Prod2    |  8       |0  |   Pk.   | NONE|
|row6 | 20.09.2018  |   203  |  Prod5    |  8       |6  |   Pk.   | DONE|
|row6 | 20.09.2018  |   203  |  Prod5    |  8       |0  |   Pk.   | NONE|
|row7 | 20.09.2018  |   205  |  Prod101  |  3       |5  |   bundle| DONE|
|row7 | 20.09.2018  |   205  |  Prod101  |  3       |5  |   bundle| NONE|
|row7 | 20.09.2018  |   205  |  Prod202  |  3       |5  |   bundle| DONE|
|row7 | 20.09.2018  |   205  |  Prod202  |  3       |5  |   bundle| NONE|
```

So, basically what i need is to insert data by row depending on **Stage**, one row with stage *DONE* and second with *NONE* - plus, in case the consumerID it matches then **Qty** value it's equal in both cases, otherwise for *NONE* value = 0 and for *DONE* the original value.
FOR **ProducID** if it matches the product, then we have to insert 4 rows. as on above table. Again matching consumerID & Prod updating/inserting stage/values.

YOur support, is highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need `IF` for this. The typical way is to left join source and target tables and create an INSERT whose WHERE selects only entries whose `target` key is null and an UPDATE whose `WHERE` selects only those that aren't null.

Comment: If you used an `IF` you'd have to execute the entire query at least once to find any matching records, before you execute the *same* query another two times to INSERT and UPDATE. Worst case, you'd have to perform 1 query for every row. With the left joins you only execute 2 queries to find *and* insert/update the data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've done a nice job laying out table structures and sample data. I'm afraid I don't follow the logic, though. Do you have a first pass at a query (or queries) you could add to your post?

Comment: @Eric Brandt is right.  If you show us your current SQL, people are much more likely to show you what to change, and you will be done quicker.